# expanded event to TreeView wpf

Tags: wpf, events, treeview, expand, hierarchicaldatatemplate

i have a treeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate, and I want add expanded event

```
<TreeView Name="files" Margin="0,0,569,108" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding s1}">
                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />                              
                                </StackPanel>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox111" Checked="FileCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="FileCheckBox_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding C}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeView>
```

how I can add event expanded?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

In XAML:

<TreeView ... TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" />

Code Behind:

public void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object s, RoutedEventArgs e) {...}

Comment: and how i run this event when the tree is expand?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.